# Interpreting variable importance for multinomial logistic regression - `nnet::multinom()` and `caret::varImp()`

Tags: r, r-caret, multinomial, nnet

I am trying to calculate and interpret the variable importance of a *multinomial logistic regression* I built using the `multinom()` function from the {nnet} R package. I want to measure the variable importance of each predictor variable contributing to the outcome variable, and the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-85/topics/varImp) of {caret} says that its function `varImp()` can do that. On the surface the code works in terms of generating some importance values, but what it doesn't do (I think - in the documentation or the function itself) is tell me how these values are calculated or what they actually are.

Here's my attempt at a reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nnet)
library(caret)

fit <- multinom(Species ~ ., data = iris) # fit model

varImp(fit)
```

And this is what I get:

```
              Overall
Sepal.Length 13.38206
Sepal.Width  24.07817
Petal.Length 37.90455
Petal.Width  18.23298
```

My question is - **what do these numbers mean**, or how can I find out what they mean? (I've tried the package documentation) Is there an alternative way where I can get an estimate of the relative variable importance?

Thank you!

Comment: May crossvalidated is the better place for this kind of question. Maybe this [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2669316?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1) is helpful.